# How to select multiple date in custom calendarView?

Tags: android, calendar

I am making custom calendar in android My requirement is that make multiple date selection same as shown in image any one have any suggestion.Till now I make calendar on view and trying to draw path according to touch but its not working for me.Here is My code:-

```
public class CalendarView extends View {

private float width; // width of one tile
private float height; // height of one tile
private int selX; // X index of selection
private int selY; // Y index of selection
private final Rect selRect = new Rect();
private GregorianCalendar month, itemmonth;// calendar instances.
private CalendarAdapter adapter;// adapter instance
private Context mContext ;
private GregorianCalendar pmonthmaxset;
private GregorianCalendar selectedDate;
private ArrayList<String> items;
private  List<String> dayString;
private GregorianCalendar pmonth; // calendar instance for previous month
/**
 * calendar instance for previous month for getting complete view
 */
private int firstDay;
private int maxWeeknumber;
private int maxP;
private int calMaxP;
private int lastWeekDay;
private int leftDays;
private int mnthlength;
private String itemvalue, curentDateString;
private DateFormat df;
private Canvas macanvas;
private Path mpath;
private float cselX; // X index of selection
private float cselY; // Y index of selection

public CalendarView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    mpath = new Path();
    RectF mrectf = new RectF(selRect);
    //mpath.ad

    month = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    itemmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    selectedDate = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();
    mContext = context;
    month.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    this.items = new ArrayList<String>();
    df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    curentDateString = df.format(selectedDate.getTime());
    dayString= new ArrayList<String>();
    macanvas = new Canvas();
    refreshDays();


}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    width = w / 7f;
    height = (w)/(7f);
    getRect(selX, selY, selRect);
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    // Draw the background...
      Paint background = new Paint();
      background.setColor( Color.GRAY);
      canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), background);


      // Draw the board...

      // Define colors for the grid lines
      Paint foreground = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
      foreground.setColor(Color.RED);
      Paint dark = new Paint();
      dark.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      Paint hilite = new Paint();
      hilite.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      Paint light = new Paint();
      light.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      // Draw the minor grid lines
      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
         canvas.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height,
               light);
         canvas.drawLine(0, i * height + 1, getWidth(), i * height
                   + 1, hilite);

      }
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

          canvas.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width,width*5,
                   light);
          canvas.drawLine(i * width+1, 0, i * width+1,width*5,
                   light);
    }

      foreground.setColor(Color.RED);
      foreground.setStyle(Style.FILL);
      foreground.setTextSize(height * 0.75f);
      foreground.setTextScaleX(width / height);
      foreground.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

      // Draw the number in the center of the tile
      FontMetrics fm = foreground.getFontMetrics();
      // Centering in X: use alignment (and X at midpoint)
      float x = width / 2;
      // Centering in Y: measure ascent/descent first
      float y = height / 2 - (fm.ascent + fm.descent) / 2;

    int k =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
             String datevalue = fillDate(k++);
            canvas.drawText(datevalue, i
                  * width + x, j * height + y, foreground);

         }
      }

    if(mpath!=null)
    {
      Paint selected = new Paint();
      selected.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      canvas.drawPath(mpath,selected);
      // canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 25, selected);
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

private void getRect(int x, int y, Rect rect) {
      rect.set((int) (x * width), (int) (y * height), (int) (x
            * width + width), (int) (y * height + height));
   }

public String fillDate(int index)
{
    String date = "";

        // separates daystring into parts.
        String[] separatedTime = dayString.get(index).split("-");
        // taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02
        String gridvalue = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*", "");
        // checking whether the day is in current month or not.
        if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) > 1) && (index < firstDay)) {
            // setting offdays to white color.
            //dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            //dayView.setClickable(false);
            //dayView.setFocusable(false);
        }
        else if ((Integer.parseInt(gridvalue) < 7) && (index > 28)) {
            //dayView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            //dayView.setClickable(false);
            //dayView.setFocusable(false);
        } else {
            // setting curent month's days in blue color.
            //dayView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

        if (dayString.get(index).equals(curentDateString)) {
            //setSelected(v);
            //previousView = v;
        } else {
            //v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_item_background);
        }

    return gridvalue;

}

public void refreshDays() {
    // clear items
    items.clear();
    dayString.clear();
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    pmonth = (GregorianCalendar) month.clone();
    // month start day. ie; sun, mon, etc
    firstDay = month.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    // finding number of weeks in current month.
    maxWeeknumber = month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
    // allocating maximum row number for the gridview.
    mnthlength = maxWeeknumber * 7;
    maxP = getMaxP(); // previous month maximum day 31,30....
    calMaxP = maxP - (firstDay - 1);// calendar offday starting 24,25 ...
    /**
     * Calendar instance for getting a complete gridview including the three
     * month's (previous,current,next) dates.
     */
    pmonthmaxset = (GregorianCalendar) pmonth.clone();
    /**
     * setting the start date as previous month's required date.
     */
    pmonthmaxset.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calMaxP + 1);

    /**
     * filling calendar gridview.
     */
    for (int n = 0; n < mnthlength; n++) {

        itemvalue = df.format(pmonthmaxset.getTime());
        pmonthmaxset.add(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 1);
        dayString.add(itemvalue);

    }
}

private int getMaxP() {
    int maxP;
    if (month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) == month
            .getActualMinimum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH)) {
        pmonth.set((month.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR) - 1),
                month.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.MONTH), 1);
    } else {
        pmonth.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH,
                month.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) - 1);
    }
    maxP = pmonth.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return maxP;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch(event.getAction())
    {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         //select((int) (event.getX() / width),
                   // (int) (event.getY() / height));
          mpath.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
          mpath.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());

        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        invalidate();
         cselX = event.getX();
         cselY = event.getY();
         mpath.lineTo(cselX,cselY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        break;

    }
    return true;
}

private void select(int x, int y) {
     selX = Math.min(Math.max(x, 0), 8);
     selY = Math.min(Math.max(y, 0), 8);
     getRect(selX, selY, selRect);

      invalidate(selRect);
   }
```

}

Comment: Check the muliple date select [@github](https://github.com/square/android-times-square/tree/master/sample)

Comment: issue is not multiple date selection issue is how to show like above image.

Answer (score -1):

You can deselect date,add to array and then user select 2nd date...

Comment: That is not an answer to the question and generally bad UX.

Answer (score -1):

With my library, you can select one date but set event dates. It likes multiple selection.

[MFCalendarView](https://github.com/MustafaFerhan/MFCalendarView)